# $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb N$. Prove $S$ $=$ $\mathbb N$

Tags: analysis

$S$ is a subset of $\mathbb N$ such that

1. $2^k$$\in$$S$ $\forall$ $k$$\in$$\mathbb N$
2. $k$$\in$$S$, $k\ge2$ then $k-1$$\in$$S$

Prove $$S=\mathbb N$$
Is this correct

$k=2$$\in$$S$ so $k-1=1$$\in$$S$

$k$$\in$$S$, $k+2\ge2$ then $(k+2)-1=k+1$$\in$$S$

Hence $S=\mathbb N$

Comment: How can you conclude that $k+2\in S$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen so that's one mistake. Besides I don't know what to do with the 2^k

Comment: Pick any positive integer $m$. If $m=1,2$ or $2^k$ for some $k$, then we know that $m\in S$. If $m$ is not of that form, then take the smallest $k$ with $2^k>m$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: @EdMo38 I can't work it out

Comment: @user480659 Ok, so we have an $m$ and the smallest $k$ with $2^k>m$. From your first condition we know that $2^k\in S$ and from the second condition we know that $2^k-1\in S$, using the second condition again, we know that $(2^k-1)-1=2^k-2\in S$. Carrying this on, we eventually reach $m$.

Comment: @EdMo38 and m belonging to S means that $\mathbb N$ is a subset of S and hence they are equal. Right?

Comment: @user480659 Yes, we are showing that any $m\in\Bbb{N}$ is also in $S$, so $\Bbb{N}\subseteq S$ which, together with $S\subseteq\Bbb{N}$ gives $S=\Bbb{N}$.

Comment: @EdMo38 okay. I was trying to prove that first 1 is in S, second if k is in S then so is k+1. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using the method that if

1. $1\in$$S$
2. $\forall$$k$$\in$$\Bbb N$, if $k$$\in$$S$ then $k+1$$\in$$S$

$S=$$\Bbb N$

First, $2\ge2$ and $2=2^1$$\in$$S$ so $2-1=1\in$$S$

Second, Let $m$ and $k$$\in$$\Bbb N$ such that $k$ is the smallest value for which $2^k$$\gt$$m$

$2^k$$\in$$S$ then so is $2^k-1$
And as $2^k-1$$\in$$S$ then so is $(2^k-1)-1$
So $2^k-l$$\in$$S$ for some $l$$\in$$\Bbb N$
Hence $2^k-l-1$$\in$$S$
Let $m=$$2^k-l-1$ so $m+1=$$2^k-l$$\in$$S$

Hence $S=$$\Bbb N$